# The union of any directed set of the closed sets of algebraic closure operator is closed?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

In "Notes on Lattice Theory" J. B., there is a theorem such that

> Let $\Gamma$ be a closure operator on a set $X$. The following are equivalent.
>
> (1) $\Gamma$ is an algebraic closure operator.
>
> (2) The union of any up-directed set of $\Gamma$-closed sets is $\Gamma$-closed.
>
> (3) The union of any chain of $\Gamma$-closed sets is $\Gamma$-closed.

and A subset $D$ of an ordered set $P$ is said to be up-directed if for every $x,y \in D$ there exists $z \in D$ with $x \leq z$ and $y \leq z$.

The definition of algebraic closure operator

> A closure operator $\Gamma$ on a set $X$ is said to be algebraic if for every $B \subseteq X$,
> $$\Gamma(B) = \bigcup \{\Gamma(F): F\ \text{is a finite subset of}\ B\}.$$

How to proof this theorem? like (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2), i cant figure out whats the up-directed set of closed set here.

Comment: what is the definition of an algebraic closure operator on $X$?

Comment: [this classical paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-064-02/S0002-9947-1948-0027263-2/S0002-9947-1948-0027263-2.pdf) seems to be the basis..

Comment: Added the definition of algebraic closure operator.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 to 2, let $\mathscr{C}$ be a an up-directed family of $\Gamma$-closed sets.
(This means that $\Gamma(C)=C$ for all $C \in \mathscr{C}$ and $C_1,C_2 \in \mathscr{C}$ implies that there is a $C_3 \in \mathscr{C}$ that contains them both (the up-directed part). Let $\hat{C}= \bigcup \mathscr{C}$ and we have to show $\hat{C}$ is closed.

Now take any finite $F \subseteq \hat{C}$. So for any $f \in F$ we have some $C_f \in \mathscr{C}$ so that $f \in C_f$. Now we apply the up-directedness (which we can extend to finitely many sets by induction) and find some $C_0 \in \mathscr{C}$ such that $C_f \subseteq C_0$ for all $f \in F$ and so $F \subseteq C_0$. It follows that $\Gamma(F) \subseteq \Gamma(C_0) = C_0 \subseteq \hat{C}$ (by $\Gamma$-closedness of $C_0$ and monotonicity of $\Gamma$ under inclusion).

So this holds for all finite subsets of $\hat{C}$ and now using the fact that $\Gamma$ is an algebraic closure:

As $$\Gamma(\hat{C}) = \bigcup \{ \Gamma(F)\mid F \subseteq \hat{C} \text{ finite }\}\} \subseteq \hat{C} \subseteq \Gamma(\hat{C})$$

so $\hat{C}$ is $\Gamma$-closed.

(2) implies (3) is trivial as a chain of subsets is an up-directed family.

Comment: According to hint in the exercise in the notes, (3) to (1) must be shown by transfinite induction on the cardinality of the set $S$ we're taking the closure of.

Comment: thanks very much! i was wondering how to whats the up-directed set here, now i can understand the relation here is set inclusion!

Comment: @maplgebra yes that’s common usage for families of subsets.